# Read only desired amount of bytes using Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I'm just creating a very simple C++ class that provides me a few methods, like `connect()` and `read()`, instead of exposing all the Boost.Asio socket calls.

Right now, I'm trying to find out how to create a method that reads only the desired amount of bytes:

```
SocketClient::read(int bytes, char* data); //reads desired amount of bytes and puts them in data, size of data>bytes!
```

Unfortunately, I found no `read_byte` function in Boost.Asio.  I do not want to drop bytes that have been received, but not yet read.

[Here is my class.](http://u8.8u.cz//code/client.cpp)

Comment: From the documentation, it is not obvious what happens with data I don't read. I **need** to read number of bytes. Exact number. Not more. Not less. If there is less, function will block. **What happens when there are more then I need?**

Comment: why can't you just use you're own internal buffering mechanism?  Read what's available, and if $bytes number of bytes are available, return that many bytes, otherwise read more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [read](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload1.html) function seems to provide exactly what you need:

> This function is used to read a certain number of bytes of data from a
>   stream. The call will block until one of the following conditions is
>   true:
>
> ```
> - The supplied buffers are full. That is, the bytes transferred
>   is equal to the sum of the buffer sizes.
> - An error occurred.
> ```

Example usage:

```
boost::asio::read(stream, boost::asio::buffer(data, size));
```

Comment: Where do I get the data stream? Is that a member of `tcp::socket`? Or can I use an instance of `socket` itself here?

Comment: yes, you can use socket directly. Anything that supports [SyncReadStream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SyncReadStream.html) concept can be used here

Comment: I have implemented the same, but some how it is not returning the actual result and the request is hanged up.